# Proposing a Documentation tag for a synonym leads to a 404 page

Tags: bug, documentation, tag-synonym-process, documentation-tags

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).
2. Click "Propose a New Tag" (the blue button along the right side of the page near the top).
3. In the "Tag" text box, type `msil`.
4. Note that two choices appear, namely `gac-msil` and `msil` (note that [msil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msil) is a synonym of [cil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cil)).  Click on `msil`.

**Expected result:** The target tag (cil in this case) gets proposed (or says that there is too little activity to be a documentation topic).

**Actual result:** Page Not Found page.

Comment: Reproduced; I've updated this report with details.